# Google Logo Animations, are they Flash, JavaScript or something else and how to generally check what is used?

Tags: javascript, flash

In Google`s logo animations, a user can often interact with the logo: for instance, like a game, where there is some button that can be pressed and stuff, but I am curious if someone could tell me what they use to create this - Flash, JavaScript, or something else?

I have a feeling that they use JavaScript, but can someone prove that? Also, how do I check this later so I can find out what they use in the future?

https://www.google.no

Comment: they use a mixture of javascript, css, html.  Older interactive logos from google were Java.  How can you prove this? please use View Source to see their code, or simply to prove it isn't Java use an iOS device or disable Java in your browser.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, nowadays, they use HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript/jQuery. Most of the time, they use `canvas` technology, and sometimes they manipulate a sprite sheet via CSS3. For sound, they use Java, but occasionally you'll see HTML5 `audio` technology, with Java as a fallback. Older Google animations were made purely with Java using HTML only as the vehicle.

Sometimes, they'll also use animated gifs as in [Heinrich Rudolf Hertzs 155th Birthday Doodle](http://www.google.com/doodles/heinrich-rudolf-hertzs-155th-birthday). (For the more simple ones).

Answer (score 2):

Google Doodles use Javascript, CSS and HTML. The quickest way to see that it's not a flash app is to right click on the doodle and if it's flash you'll see on the right click menu "About Adobe Flash Player". If it doesn't say that it's not flash.

Comment: Ah, I guess that was simply obvious, but fun that I didn`t think of that :) Thanks!

Comment: Up until fairly recently, Flash was used for sound. So for example, the Pac-Man doodle uses Flash for sound, without Flash it's without sound effects. More recent ones, like the Moog doodle, use browser sound APIs, and fallback on Flash for sound in browsers where sound API is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
they use javascript to animate the elements of the DOM and css sprite/atlases for the graphics.

A nice article on [how Google Doodles works](http://zoompf.com/2012/04/how-do-google-animated-doodles-work)

A step-by-step tutorial to create your own Google doodle [with css3 animations](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/google-doodle-animation-in-css3-without-javascript)

Edit:
The doodle at www.google.no is also build with HTML5 canvas elements.